# Java: Check if every single digit of a number is within a range

Tags: java, arrays, loops, boolean

I am making a method of a class that takes two integers as arguments. It checks every single digit of the first one and makes sure they are less than or equal to the second one.

```
public static boolean digitRange(int x, int limit) {
    String number= Integer.toString(x);
    char[] digits=number.toCharArray();
    boolean result=false;
    for(char c: digits) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c))>limit) {
            result=false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The expected output for say 0 and 5 would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(digitRange(0,5));//0 is les than or equal to 5. 
                                        //Therefore true is printed. 
}
```

However, I am getting false in every single scenario and I cannot find why.
Could someone help me correct the digitRange method, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String number= Integer.toString(x);
char[] digits=number.toCharArray();
boolean result=false;
for(char c: digits) {
    if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c))>limit) {
        result=false;
    }
}
return result;
```

You never set `result` to `true` anywhere.  Change to

```
boolean result=true;
```

However, consider a totally different approach:

```
public static boolean digitRange(int x, int limit)
{
    int t = Math.abs(x);
    while (t > 0)
    {
        if (t % 10 > limit)
            return false;
        t /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never set the result value to true. Simply return once you have established false as you no longer need to check, and if you make your way out of the iteration return true.

```
public static boolean digitRange(int x, int limit) {
    String number= Integer.toString(x);
    char[] digits=number.toCharArray();

    for(char c: digits) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c))>limit) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function accepts two numbers and checks each digit is within the range of the second number and return true if all digits are less than the second number or it returns false.

```
public boolean check(int one,int two){
    while(one>0){
        if(one%10>two)
            return false;
        one=one/10;
    }
    return true;
}
```